# Can I stick ceiling acoustic panels to my wall with intent to reduce room echo?

Tags: noise-reduction, acoustic

I know it's far from ideal, but I have a few excess cartons of ceiling tiles. If I stick some to my walls, will it help to noticeably reduce my room's echo or reverberation? Or will the difference be so minimal, that I will be wasting my time?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the room, and how many tiles do you have?

Comment: This is my basement room. 12ft x 17ft. Floor to ceiling height is 7ft. I don't want to completely cover the walls with ceiling tiles though, as it will look ugly

Answer (score 1):

Any plain wall is a sound board. Any application of materials that are porous, or have 33 degree multiple angles will reduce the amount that sound waves bounce. The acoustic tiles will provide a reduction in the echo. And will in turn provide a better sound insulating factor. By themselves they will not provide the recording studio atmosphere. You will need a entirely different set of materials and structural application.